# What is the name of this "generalized sum"?

Tags: functions, summation, average

I'm looking for the name of this quite basic function:

$X=\sqrt[\alpha]{\sum_i{x_i^\alpha}}$ ($\alpha\in\mathbb R$)

It's a kind of "generalized sum":

- $\alpha=1$ : $X=\sum_i{x_i}$
- $\alpha\to\infty$ : $X=\max(x_i)$

I've spend hours looking on the net, but search engines are not very useful in this.

Comment: Can't find the name?Well put it by your name IOranger's Sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$X=\left(\sum_i x_i^\alpha\right)^{1/\alpha}$$ is the $p$-norm of the vector $(x_i)_i$ where $p=\alpha$ (at least if $\alpha\ge 1$). Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_norm#p-norm).